# Heroku Connect: initial load into Heroku with million of records from Salesforce

Tags: heroku-connect

I would like to see if someone already worked on adding Heroku Connect in an existing org where they needed to bring many millions of records into Heroku.

Does it require custom load script or can Heroku Connect using multiple batches?

Comment: Heroku connect uses bulk api to load records usually in batches of 5000. It takes some time to do initial load and also as and when you change metadata. The loading is managed by Heroku connect completely.

Comment: That is brilliant @manjit5190 , have you ever tried that in real-world project?

Comment: Yes. With about 2.2 million records maximum.

Comment: Hey @manjit5190, based on the docs when the load is more than 10,000 records seems to use Bulk API in batches of up to 150,000 records. Have seen that?

Answer (score 2):

**API call usage**

The number of API calls used by Heroku Connect will depend on a number of factors:

- the total number of mappings
- the directionality of each mapping (read only or read/write)
- the synchronization mode of each mapping (polling or streaming) (see synchronization mode)
  Depending on the API used and the directionality of the mapping, Heroku Connect will batch changes differently.

For changes to records being **read** from Salesforce, Heroku Connect will use:

- the SOAP API in batches of up to 2000 records OR
- the Bulk API in batches of up to 150,000 records

For changes to records being **written** to Salesforce, Heroku Connect will use:

- the SOAP API in batches of up to 200 records OR
- the Bulk API in batches of 2,000 to 10,000 records
  None of these calls will count towards your daily SOAP or Bulk API limits.

- As per [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/reading-data-from-salesforce-with-heroku-connect)

Comment: That is great info, have you ever implemented this? I'm hoping somebody that already implemented this can chime in to see if there is any gotcha during implementation phase.